# Alternative to if/then when using generics

Tags: c#, design-patterns

What is the better alternative to use of if/then in the following logic:

```
    public void DoSomething <T>()
    {
        if (typeof (T) == typeof (A))
        {

        }
        else if (typeof (T) == typeof (B))
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with this approach that you want to change it?

Comment: Having two different methods? This doesn't sound like a good fit for generics.

Comment: The better alternative IMHO would be to have `A` and `B` derive from a common base class, have `DoSomething()` implemented as a virtual method of the base class, and override it in `A` and `B`. This may be too far enough from your current design to suit you, though.

Comment: @SystemDown: It's not really OOP-ish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably overload the method instead:

```
public void DoSomething(A item)
{
   ...
}

public void DoSomething(B item)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please advise - what should be the signature of such method in the interface?

Comment: @user2911759 Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. The signature would be exactly what I put in my answer, except with no body, because it's an interface not a class (assuming that `A` and `B` really are the types that you are using)

Comment: can I just somehow have only one method signature in interface (my class is derived from this interface)? Or should I have 2: 'void DoSomething(A item);'void DoSomething(B item);'

Comment: @user2911759 If the two types `A` and `B` are unrelated by inheritance, then definitely it's cleaner to have two separate methods.

Comment: they are related: both are derived from same interface.

Comment: @user2911759 Well if there was some method that could be overridden in each method, you could call that instead, but without more information about what you want to do in `DoSomething()` it's hard to say. But you would still not be using generics to do so! Maybe you should make a new question but with a lot more details about what you want to do in the `DoSomething()` depending on the type.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that is a code smell.

<strike>Something like:</strike>

```
public void DoSomething <T>() where T : A
{

}

public void DoSomething <T>() where T : B
{

}
```

If you are doing this though, then it stuill feel a bit smelly.  A better solution would to have both A & B inherid a common interface and then have a single method `where T : IMyNewInterface`.

If that's really not possible then this might not be a problem to solve this way, or the architecture might need revisiting.

**CORRECTION**

The above code is not valid, as Eric stated in the comment below.  Generics do not form part of the signature, so can't be used in a overload.

The only other option is a normal overload:

```
public void DoSomething(A a)
{

}

public void DoSomething(B b)    {

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I really need generics in this case though, or is it enough to have:                                                            'public void DoSomething (A objectA) 
{

}

public void DoSomething (B objectB) 
{

}'

Comment: Constraints are not part of the signature. This is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want your objects to be of a similar type or have similar method naming when you're using generics.

With what you've described, this is my preferred pattern:

```
public void DoSomethingA() { }
public void DoSomethingB() { }
```